# How can I fix the missing /NST/AutoNeoGrub0.mbr error on Windows 8?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 onto my Windows 8 UEFI HP Pavilion g6 laptop. I installed ubuntu by clicking 'something else' in the installation window.
I then made 4 partitions: /boot , / , /home and a swap partition. It installed without a hitch, and it booted straight into Windows 8. Because I knew Windows 8 wouldn't find Ubuntu, I used EasyBCD to add the OS to the boot list.
When I boot, it comes up with the boot manager, showing Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I can boot into 8 perfectly fine, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu it comes up with a 0xc000007c error saying that /NST/AutoNeoGrub0.mbr is missing or corrupt. It's definitely in there, as I have checked.
Also I have already run the recommended fix on Boot Repair using the live CD.
Could somebody please help me out with this? I'm getting nowhere.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

EasyBCD doesn't work with UEFI. Refer to their [FAQ](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/FAQ).

> Does EasyBCD have EFI support? No, not yet.

Refer instead to this question: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: So would starting in legacy BIOS solve the problem?

Comment: @Pacerier no because that's looking for a MBR partitioned disk with a MBR bootloader, none of which an EFI based Windows computer have.